# How to get inner for-loop to run all the way through before moving onto next increment of outer loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I am making a program i wrote for a uni project more expansive, and before i was working with a 3x3 matrix, but now its a 15 by 15 matrix, and i want to make a for loop to fill the values, rather than what i have currently. Ive made this sample code a bit smaller, but this is what i want to put into a for loop:

```
distance_matrix=
[array1[0]-array2[0], array1[1]-array2[0], array1[2]-array2[0], array1[3]-array2[0],array1[4]-array2[0]],
[array1[0]-array2[1], array1[1]-array2[1], array1[2]-array2[1], array1[3]-array2[1],array1[4]-array2[1]],
[array1[0]-array2[2], array1[1]-array2[2], array1[2]-array2[2], array1[3]-array2[2],array1[4]-array2[2]],
[array1[0]-array2[3], array1[1]-array2[3], array1[2]-array2[3], array1[3]-array2[3],array1[4]-array2[3]],
[array1[0]-array2[4], array1[1]-array2[4], array1[2]-array2[4], array1[3]-array2[4],array1[4]-array2[4]]
```

So this is a 5x5 matrix. As you can see, the values for each entry are the difference between values in the 2 arrays. My first thought to loop this was a 2 layer nested for loop, but that only generated a 5x1 matrix, with the values on the diagonal, the (i,i) values. it looked like this:

```
distance_matrix=[[0 for x in range(0,5)] for y in range(0,5)]
for i range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,5):
        distance_matrix[i][j]=array1[i]-array2[j]
```

then i tried with an if statement, just a list that i could then reshape, and setting the value that stays constant over the rows in the outer loop,but this generated again a list of length 5 (and i cant really figure out why):

```
distance_matrix_list=[]
    for col_val in range(0,5):
        first_value=array1[col_val]
        for row_val in range(0,5)):
            if row_val<5):
                distance_matrix_list.append([first_value-array2[row_val]])
        
        distance_matrix=np.array(distance_matrix_list)
        distance_matrix.reshape((5,5))
```

this must be really obvious and im quite frustrated that im missing this. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code snippet, apart from some typos should work just fine. You do however need to switch i and j, when assigning the indicies. This works fine for me:

```
distance_matrix=[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        distance_matrix[i][j] = array1[j] - array2[i]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! a few indexing typos and indenting errors meant i wasnt getting it. knowing that it was actually right allowed me to see properly what was happening. thanks!

Comment: If this helped I would appreciate if you marked the answer as correct.